# Could someone give me an overview for a php 'anonymous confessions' script?

Tags: php, blogs, publishing, anonymous

I don't need to know every minute detail, I'll do my own research, but if I wanted to write a script that allowed anonymous visitors to a site to post confessions on the site for all to see, no 'approval'.. process, with comments, and captcha. It'd also need to have a backend for deletions of comments and 'confession' posts - what would be an overview of what I'd need to do/learn in php to achieve that.  I have a basic understanding of php, enough to modify existing scripts.  IF there is any script out there that I could base this on, I would love to know what its called.

Thanks.

Comment: The Ruby on Rails guide will walk you through doing this and more (a blog) in a couple hours, for what it's worth.

Comment: He asked for PHP, why recommend a framework for Ruby? PHP has its own frameworks, and they all have the same blog tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just basic CRUD actions virtually *every* dynamic website does. Whether you call them comments or blog posts or forum threads or confessions, it's just creating, reading, updating and deleting some objects represented by rows in a database.

A good beginners PHP book will walk you through building something that does all those things (a blog, a CMS, etc)... I recommend the book [Build Your Own Database Driven Website With PHP & MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980576814).

Answer (score 1):

Programming something like this from scratch is not something I would recommend for the inexperienced. Your needs would probably be better served by a pre-packaged solution such as [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/), combined with third-party templates and plug-ins.

If you'd like to learn to do it yourself, buy a PHP/MySQL book, start with a minimal version of your project, and work your way up.

Comment: Why not? This is like the regular topic of a CS level 3 class. It's quite easy to do _once you learn some things_